# ups to give few minutes for about 20 PCs and 10 Printers

Tags: ups, battery

We've a problem in the electricity current for three months right now,

I was tasked to get the best solution, and it should be cost effective also, for allowing our application users to save and shutdown their PCs, and complete the printing jobs they sent to the printers.

the problem is we don't need to place a ups for every PCs, or office, we need a One centerlized solution that is a one UPS for all.

any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its going to be a lot more cost effective to get a UPS for each device you want to keep online, excluding large laser printers, than to get something for the whole office.

A solution like you seem to want is going to require some large equipment purchases (I'd estimate something like 15 to 20k) and then a few thousand to have an electrician wire it all into the existing electrical system. One of my customers had this done for a slightly larger organization than you're describing, about 15 to 20% larger, and his TCO was about 24k after everything.

Comment: could you give me some examples for these equipment

Answer (score 0):

What you need/want is a large centralized UPS, keep in mind that printers for example are very power hungry devices, this will make the whole thing expensive. Something like this http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=suvt30kh3b4s is what you will want. You have to actually figure out the max load from you equipment and your required back up time first though.